# Delete all files via mv date?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, mv

Everyday new audio files are created in `dir1`.

Sometime I move (`mv`) some files from `dir1` to `dir2`

I want to delete all the files in `dir2` that was moved before 20th June

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with first answer: it seems it's possible. mv preserves mtime (modification time), but it changes ctime (change time). So it's should be possible to archieve this by doing `find dir2 -ctime +30 -delete` (or whatever other expression with ctime).

PS: and don't forget to double-check your command by running it with `-print` instead of `-delete` :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible, because `mv` preserves the original mtime of the file when it's moved, so there's no record (within the file metadata) of when a file was moved.